# Standarize a 3D NumPy array that has been padded with np.nan

Tags: python, numpy, normalize, mfcc

I have a 3D matrix with a shape like (100, 40, 170).

This matrix has been padded to reach the max length of 170 by filling up with np.nan (NaN).

The values in the matrix represent MFCC coefficients from audio data extracted from the [UrbanSound8K dataset](https://urbansounddataset.weebly.com/urbansound8k.html), using LibRosa (Python).

(Source notebook and data are shared, check the end of the post)

I need to normalize this matrix by the axis=2, by:

1. Compute the mean over the 3th axis, ignoring elements equal to np.nan
2. Compute std dev over the 3th axis, ignoring elements equal to np.nan
3. Subtract the mean to every element that is not equal to np.nan
4. Divide by the std dev every element that is not equal to np.nan

I have tried many different ways and did not worked. Other posts point to the use of sklearn but the normalization tools from that library are not friendly with 3D matrices... so, by now, this is my best approach:

```
# Compute mean and std dev matrices (omitting NaN and keeping shapes)
mean = np.nanmean(X_nan, axis=2, keepdims=True)
std = np.nanstd(X_nan, axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

But then when I subtract and divide I get errors:

```
X_norm -= mean
X_norm /= std
```

The Warning message says:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

And when I check just the first elements of the normalized and original matrices, I see:

```
# Original
array([[[-58.95327, -58.95327,        -58.95327,       ...,          
                     nan,             nan,            nan],

# Normalized
array([[[-inf,       -inf,            -inf,            ...,
                     inf,             inf,             inf],
```

Note that the **-inf** values where introduced when subtracting the mean, not for dividing.

Can you recommend me a way to compute both metrics and do the subtraction and division with NumPy omitting the padded values?

Thank you very much!

The data was generated with this notebook (note that repo is under development!): [Urban sound classification with CNN](https://github.com/GorillaBus/urban-audio-classifier/blob/master/2-pre-processing.ipynb)

I have uploaded the data (pickled X and y): [MFCC Coeffs X and Y](https://transfernow.net/ddl/us8k-mfcc)

Comment: This might be a perfect application for [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

Comment: Can you post intermediate values too please?

Comment: @Linuxios I did read about the use of masked but I'm also trying to find the right way to do it with that.

Comment: @NilsWerner Sure, I added some more examples.

Comment: All your values are almost the same, no wonder `stddev` is zero. Does the same thing happen with random 3D tensor?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Hi, well in those examples data is very similar, yes, but is not the case for all the elements (I will update it now). And yes, with tensors that has no NaN padding values it works fine.

Comment: @EduardoG.R. All your values in normalized array are `np.inf`? And are you sure it happens after the mean is subtracted?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Yes. In some previous attemps I didn't get the -inf values but still the result was not the expected. I think there should be an easy way to normalize a matrix with more than 2 dimensions omitting all elements introduced by padding (in this case with a value of np.nan)

Comment: Most probably it's due to values being very close to each other in general and `mean - element` going towards numerical precision. For `stddev` you further divide that value by number of elements and take `sqrt` from that, which falls below that threshold. You should compare calculated mean to the values and see, how much is left after subtraction. And if the `mean` is close enough to zero, just input zero. What's this data anyway, looks pretty strange

Comment: @SzymonMaszke this are MFCC coefficients from audio samples. Padded was used because all audio files are of varying durations. There are many different theories on how to normalize MFCC and many even tell that normalizing MFCC, sometimes, is not really required. But I'd like to do my own experiments and see how the same mode architecture performs with standard and normalized data, training for the same amount of epochs.

Comment: If tips above didn't help, you would be better off providing us your data sample generating this behavior so we could investigate on our own. You could post a link to download your saved tensor in `.npz` format or pickle of some sort.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Sure! let me get back home and I'll prepare a notebook and some saved data, thanks for your help!

Comment: @SzymonMaszke hi again, I just updated the post with a notebook and pickle data if you like to experiment with it, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197007/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-eduardo-g-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this solution:

```
X_norm = np.where(np.isnan(X_nan), np.nan, X_nan - mean)
X_norm = np.where(X_norm == 0, 0, X_norm/std)
```

also give warning, but looks like work correct.

std can be 0 only when all elements are the same, but in this case the mean is equal to elements and after subtraction you obtain all zeros. So second np.where fix this situation.

Comment: This seems to work @Soslan! Let me to some checkings and I'll come back to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Does the solution works for you, or there is another problem?